# My text doesn't show up in a new window, what could be the problem?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling

I'm writing a code that solves sudoku's. When I open a new window (with toplevel), it doesn't show any text on it. I get an error but I don't know what it means? Can anybody please help me?

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from winsound import *

rootdescription = tkinter.Tk()
rootdescription.geometry("800x800")
rootdescription['cursor'] = 'tcross'
rootdescription.title("Sudoku Solver - Description")

def inputwindow():
    inputwindow = tkinter.Toplevel()
    inputwindow.geometry("800x800")
    inputwindow['cursor'] = 'tcross'
    inputwindow.title("Sudoku Solver - InputWindow")
```

I created my two windows as shown above.

```py
startpage = Frame(rootdescription)
startpage.pack()
ins1page = Frame(rootdescription)
ins2page = Frame(rootdescription)
inputpage = Frame(rootdescription)
```

I didn't know if the information above was relevant but I posted it anyway.

Below you can find the code I used to create a button to the next window.

```py
fill1 = tkinter.Button(inputpage, text="Fill the Sudoku in!", relief=GROOVE, font='courier 10', width=86, height=40,
command=lambda:[inputwindow(), rootdescription.withdraw()])
fill1.pack()
def on_enter(e):
    fill1['background'] = 'black'
    fill1['foreground'] = 'white'
def on_leave(e):
    fill1['background'] = 'SystemButtonFace'
    fill1['foreground'] = 'black'
fill1.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
fill1.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)
```

```py
rootdescription.mainloop()
inputwindow.mainloop()
```

The text below won't show up in the window, I really don't know why.

```py
check = Frame(inputwindow)

cline1 = StringVar()
clabel1 = Label(inputwindow, textvariable=cline1, wraplength=700, font='courier 10')
cline1.set("_______________________________________________________________________________________")
clabel1.pack()
```

This is the error it gives me each time:

```py
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\V-FPS-01\Home-Edu$\93010858\Documents\informatica\Sudoku Solver.py", line 252, in <module>
    rootdescription.mainloop()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1420, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

---

I changed the order of the last two pieces of code, it now looks like this:

```py
check = Frame(inputwindow)

cline1 = StringVar()
clabel1 = Label(inputwindow, textvariable=cline1, wraplength=700, font='courier 10')
cline1.set("_______________________________________________________________________________________")
clabel1.pack()

rootdescription.mainloop()
inputwindow.mainloop()
```

I get another error now but I still don't know how to solve my problem.
Currently the error looks like this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\V-FPS-01\Home-Edu$\93010858\Documents\informatica\Sudoku Solver.py", line 252, in <module>
    check = Frame(inputwindow)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 740, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 557, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2561, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2530, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

---

I thought that the program confused the names of the window and the function (because the are the same), but changing them doesn't seem to make any difference.

---

Here is a runnable code:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from winsound import *

rootdescription = tkinter.Tk()
rootdescription.geometry("800x800")
rootdescription['cursor'] = 'tcross'
rootdescription.title("Sudoku Solver - Description")

def inputwindowf():
    inputwindow = tkinter.Toplevel()
    inputwindow.geometry("800x800")
    inputwindow['cursor'] = 'tcross'
    inputwindow.title("Sudoku Solver - InputWindow")

inputpage = Frame(rootdescription)
inputpage.pack()

fill1 = tkinter.Button(inputpage, text="Fill the Sudoku in!", relief=GROOVE, font='courier 10', width=86, height=40,
command=lambda:[inputwindowf(), rootdescription.withdraw()])
fill1.pack()
def on_enter(e):
    fill1['background'] = 'black'
    fill1['foreground'] = 'white'
def on_leave(e):
    fill1['background'] = 'SystemButtonFace'
    fill1['foreground'] = 'black'
fill1.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
fill1.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

rootdescription.mainloop()
inputwindow.mainloop()

check = Frame(inputwindow)

cline1 = StringVar()
clabel1 = Label(inputwindow, textvariable=cline1, wraplength=700, font='courier 10')
cline1.set("_______________________________________________________________________________________")
clabel1.pack()
```

The last 6 lines need to go on the new window; inputwindow.

Comment: It is not clear where the last block of posted code is put.  Inside `inputwindow()` function?

Comment: @acw1668 the code I posted has the same order as shown.

Comment: you're using `inputwindow` as both a function and a variable. That may not be the only problem, but it's the root cause of the `'function' object has no attribute 'tk'` error.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried to change all function names to `inputwindowf` but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Your example is very difficult to understand, and difficult for us to run. Please try to condense the code down to a single runnable [mcve] rather than a bunch of disjointed blocks of code. And please don't include code that is irrelevant, such as bindings, cursors, window titles, and so on.

Comment: Give me a minute...

Comment: First you should not call mainloop() twice, just `rootdescription.mainloop()` is enough.  Second, statements after mainloop() will not be executed until root window is destroyed.  Finally, `inputwindow` is local variable inside `inputwindowf()`, so it cannot be accessed outside the function.

Comment: Are you saying that I need to put everything that needs to go on the inputwindow under `def inputwindowf():`?

Comment: Yes, all lines after `mainloop()` should be put into `inputwindowf()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried doing that, but the text is still not visable. I also tried it with `check.pack()` right after `check = Frame(inputwindow)`, but still no text. (It does all need to be indented, right?)

Comment: It is because you have used `ttk.Label` instead of `tkinter.Label` and so the `StringVar` (`cline1`) is garbage collected.  Try keeping a reference of `cline1` like `clabel1.var = cline1`.  Or use `tkinter.Label`.